# How to Remove Repeating Local Notifications Wisely (Swift 4)?

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, local, lifecycle

I have an app that triggers local notifications every 30 minutes from the moment a certain button is tapped (both in the foreground and the background). I learned how to remove those notifications when another button is tapped or when the view controller is dismissed. This is done through:
**UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()**
It works just fine. However, if the user force-quits (shuts down manually) the app by swiping up in multitasking mode, this is when strange things start happening. By default, the terminated app doesn’t remove those pending push notifications and they keep coming even if the app is closed.

What I learned is that there are several states in the app’s lifecycle in which the app can be killed. Accordingly, there are several methods in the App Delegate that we can use to trigger the mentioned code to remove the notifications (otherwise they keep coming).

So, when we are in foreground and tap the home button (or swipe up with iPhone X) to switch to multitasking mode (choosing between active apps or deleting them), this is the time for applicationWillResignActive – we can start observing for app termination in here (maybe by means of observing applicationWillTerminate and using a certain method as a selector) and remove those notifications upon terminating (strangely enough, applicationWillTerminate doesn’t always work on its own).

However, if you switch to another app and then go back to multitasking mode, the app is in background mode this time (not inactive mode). So, there seems to be no way to trigger certain methods and observe for certain things when the app is already in background mode. I wonder if any? In this case applicationDidEnterBackground doesn’t work either. Everything ends up with **“Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 9”**

*So, how do you remove all pending notifications when your app is in background mode and is about to be terminated by the user? If it’s in background mode and is not going to be terminated by the user, the notifications need to stay active.
If there is a solution, please help. Or maybe there is a better way to remove pending (active) local notifications when the view controller is dismissed (it’s not the only and main view controller in the app) and when the user terminates/shuts down the app in inactive or background state? Thanks for your help.*

Answer (score 0):

You have few options for when the app is about to become NOT active:

```
func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}
```

In your case, you should probably remove notifications in all of them, and add them again in the other functions that complement them, for example:

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}
```

I believe it is good practice to add and remove the notifications in the `UIViewController` life cycle methods, instead of in the app level life cycle

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My response happens to be too long so I put it as an answer below. Please take a look at it.

Comment: I cannot see it and it shouldn't be allowed anyways, you can explain briefly here instead of a very long response

Comment: Thanks for reply. Notifications should stay when the app is about to or has already gone background since this is the very state that needs those notifications (otherwise why bother implementing those notifications anyways?) When the app is already suspended (in the bg), it cannot observe for app termination (appWillTerminate), which is why it “terminates due to signal 9” if the app with active notifications is already in bg and then gets force-quit by the user (app’s terminated,notifications are pending). This is probably because the app doesn’t have a chance to respond to this user behavior.

Comment: We are talking about local notifications (not remote ones). So, manipulating the view controller’s lifecycle doesn’t solve this problem. I use view did load and deinit methods to add and remove notifications when the vc is loaded and dismissed but when the app is force-quit, the deinit method doesn’t get called. I also add / remove notifications through observing AppDelegate’s methods, and they work just fine, expect for appWillTerminate, which is called only if the app is not suspended. The only way out is to come up with a workaround to call appWillTerminate in the background. Any ideas?